# neural networks for Farsi OCR

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, ocr, backpropagation

I'm trying to implement a **farsi OCR** using neural networks,I am using 5000 training examples each is a 70 * 79 matrix,concretely I have a 5530 units **input** layer and one hidden layer(4000 units) and a 38 units **output**.

what training algorithm should I use for **faster** and better result(backprop,PSO,genetic,...)?
I ran the implement using **back propagation** but it took a very long time,I had to cancel the process,should I use another algorithm or should I reduce my dimensions or .... ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular back-propagation is generally very slow. Try some faster variation like adding momentum or rprop.

Still expect it to be very slow, as you have over 22 million connections in just the first layer.